# How can a torrent be downloaded faster than the speed of my Internet connection?

Tags: speed, bittorrent

I have a 256 kbit/s connection and normally see download speeds around 30 kilobytes/second.

However, sometimes when I download torrents the download speed shows as 1.1 MBps. How is this possible?

Comment: Does your ISp provide some sort of super charge mode?  I the possibility is you have a faster connection then you realize

Comment: It is probably some kind of data compression.  Some kinds of data compress better than others.

Comment: Is it possible that your ISP puts multiple customers in a single high-bandwidth LAN and your client finds local peers in it?

Comment: but the super charge mode applicable for only torrent?

Comment: Some ISPs provide you with a huge connection and guarantee you what you pay for. So in your case this could mean you are guaranteed 256 kbit/s, but if most of the grid is idle you will be able to go above the limits. I have some friends who can do this as well. It's not only applicable to torrents, but also ordinary HTTP/FTP downloads.

Comment: Some BitTorrent clients allow you to see who your other peers are. Do a trace route on them to see how many hops away they are and if they're local.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.networkstraining.com/peer-to-peer-vs-client-server-network/

I saw this website that approves Mitrajit Chandra's answer.

> The speed of your internet connection may have no bearing on the time it takes for your files to download.

So, it's most likely due to peer to peer network.

Comment: Mitrajit Chandra's is wrong and the website you linked does confirm anything.

Comment: The speed of your internet connection may have no bearing on the time it takes for your files to download+Computer Network books. P2P network seems to gain as much bandwidth as that of their peers computers(not their computers' internet bandwidth) rather than depending on the internet bandwidth.

Answer (score -2):

It's because Torrent uses peer-to-peer technology. The bandwidth of your ISP is for normal internet(direct) speeds. Most of the time peer-to-peer has a higher speed than normal internet speed.

Your situation was possible because maybe there was a computer in your same ISP network seeding the file.

[An image of the architecture I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnZ3H.png)

Comment: This is wrong.  P2P has nothing to do with this.  It doesnt mater if the peers are on the same ISP,  as the user is still limited to his maximum download bandwidth.

Comment: Users are limited to the download bandwidth from a much upper level and in the lower level of the network with local ISP routers, there are no limitations. So in that network, they can exceed the given download bandwidth. [Screenshot of the architecture I am talking about](https://i.imgur.com/4xMpYV7.png)